# Python dictionary values in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, dictionary

How to use python dictionary values in javascript?
Please give a sample js code to scrape the dictionary values from the .py file to javascript.

Comment: You need to serialise the data? - That's the entire point of serialising anything. Transfer data between different technologies. Hence why ajax requires you to serialise your forms before you submit them, in order for the server to make sense of the data.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly. We need more information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads)
Take a look at this example

```
>>> import json
>>> m = {'json_try': 'True', 'price': 99.99}
>>> m
{'json_try': 'True', 'price': 99.99}
```

Then

```
>>> m = json.dumps(m)
>>> m
'{"json_try": "True", "price": 99.99}'
>>> loaded_m = json.loads(m)
>>> loaded_m
{'json_try': 'True', 'price': 99.99}
```

Read more [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)